# How to initialize, I get NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, dialog, nullpointerexception

In my main file, in `private class MyDiary` I set `OnItemLongClickListener` like this:

```
ListView list = getListView();
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    new EditListItemDialog(view.getContext()).show();

                return true;       
            }
        });
```

Then, in`EditListItemDialog` file I attempt to add new value to the table of rows(table is displayed in previous file):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    fragment_monday.add(((TextView) v).getText().toString());//here is your updated(or not updated) text
    dismiss();
}
```

`fragment_monday` is an xml for my first file to utilize the list view like this:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:padding="0dp" >



                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                         <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:longClickable="true"
     >

</ListView>



             </RelativeLayout>



                </LinearLayout>
```

At the end, when I click confirm button in `EditListItemDialog` to change the data, the app crashes and I get `NullPointer Exception` at line 37 which is second snipped, 3rd line. 
I am guessing that `fragment_monda`y is not set properly but I don't really know what to do with it in order to make this thing work.
Can anybody help?

Here is the LogCat output:

```
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at com.example.classorganizer.EditListItemDialog.onClick(EditListItemDialog.java:37)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-21 09:18:53.009: E/AndroidRuntime(5483):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also tried moving first snipped of code from private class MyDiary to private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter but no change.

Full code to EditListItemDialog:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

class EditListItemDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

private View editText;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_text_dialog);//here is your xml with EditText and 'Ok' and 'Cancel' buttons
    View btnOk = findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private List<String> fragment_monday;

public EditListItemDialog(Context context, List<String> fragment_monday) {
    super(context);
    this.fragment_monday = fragment_monday;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    fragment_monday.add(((TextView) v).getText().toString());//here is your updated(or not updated) text
    dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: What's fragment_monday?

Comment: @PareshMayani 30 seconds

Comment: fragment_monday probably should be a type of List, isn't it? Where are  instantiating it?

Comment: @lisoslaw what's this 30 seconds? I asked you to post `logcat` output so that we can analyse it and can suggest solutions.

Comment: @PareshMayani I said 30 seconds and it will be posted. And is posted now.

Comment: @Keya I don't know where it is instantiated. Sorry but I used recipe from the book

Comment: what is line no 37... you found nullpointer exception...check this

Comment: @lisoslaw something on line 37 is null. EditText initialization fails. I don't see a EditText in your xml posted.

Comment: Well, you don't the code?  In your whatever bit of code you have can you find the fragment_monday and see where is it instantiated?

Comment: @Amardeep yes I know, it is 3rd line of my second snipped. I believe it;s about fragment_monday

Comment: Post the code of `EditListItemDialog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understant, you have two constructors for EditListItemDialog. One with fragment_monday and another without it. So, if you create your object with the help of first constructor, fragment_monday was equal to null.

Just replace

```
public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

With this

```
public EditListItemDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.fragment_monday = new  List<String>();
}
```

I don't know whether all will be ok, but it will prevent Null Pointer Exception;

Comment: As laalto said, just stop use first constructor. If you want to use fragment_monday, you need to pass correct parameter List<String> fragment_monday in EditListItemDialog constructor.

Comment: Do you understand, for what you use fragment_monday variable?

Comment: To direct the new data into the list

Comment: I have  private List<String> fragment_monday; in EditListItemDialog

Comment: Yes you are. But if you use first constructor to create EditListItemDialog, it not initialized. If it does not matter for another classes, you can add string this.fragment_monday = new List<String>() at the first constructor to initialize this variable.

Comment: Can you point me to my first constructor please? Sorry for being so stupid but I learned from the recipe in the book and not everything is clear to me yet

Comment: I cannot remove fragment_monday from line 37 in my EditListItemDialog because then list is not being updated. Although when I leave it I don't know where else I need to fix the code.

Comment: Even if I delete first Constructor and only second remains, the NPE occurs and app crashes...

Comment: it complains that Cannot instantiate the type List<String>

Comment: this is in EditListItemDialog in the second remaining constructor

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thats right, List is abstract class. Try to use this.fragment_monday = new  ArrayList<String>();

Comment: indeed this removed NPE, app doesn;t crash but the row is not being updated with new data...

Answer (score 0):

You have two constructors in `EditListItemDialog`, out of which only the other initializes `fragment_monday`. In your `onItemLongClick()` code you're using the 1-arg constructor that doesn't initialize that variable. `onClick()` uses `fragment_monday` and there's your NPE.

To fix it, either

- remove the 1-arg constructor and use the 2-arg constructor only, or
- initialize `fragment_monda` to reasonable defaults in the 1-arg constructor as well.